# Make your NPM package support multiple versions of peer dependency

Tags: javascript, npm, dependencies

I have a package on NPM that is using React version 15 as peer dependency. However, I want it to stop from throwing warnings for users that upgraded their React version. How do I make package support both version 15 and 16?

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0"
  },
```

which is the most convenient way to deal with these?

Is `"*15.0.0"` good enough?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To address a range you can use following notation :

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react-dom": "15 - 16"
}
```

Makes it really easy to define a range as well.

You can test them out here : https://semver.npmjs.com/

Comment: I tried to publish my library using this approach, it does not work!

Answer (score 42):

What about:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0",
  "react-dom": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just checked some other packages on GitHub how they do it.

Using `*` didn't work out for me and therefore seems like bad practice anyway.

Better solution:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=0.14.0 <= 16",
    "react-dom": ">=0.14.0 <= 16"
  }
```